# Where can I find Spring 3 IoC JavaConfig (annotations) tutorials?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

Where can I find Spring 3 IoC JavaConfig (annotations) tutorial? If possible, please provide tutorials with source code example in SpringSource Tool Suite/maven project.

Thanks.

Update: I would like to have working examples with source code that I can immediately compile and run. There a number of old working examples for Spring 2 IoC (e.g. books' examples etc) but I still can't find for Spring 3 IoC. Thanks.

Comment: There is an operational maven standalone example on my blog: http://tshikatshikaaa.blogspot.nl/2012/08/spring-ioc-container-with-annotations.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mkyong.com have few examples ([1](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-javaconfig-example/), [2](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-javaconfig-import-example/)) with source code. Finally found answer for my first stackoverflow question after about half a year.

Answer (score 3):

Start with:

**Spring Reference: [Java-based container configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java)**

If there's anything you don't understand, ask specific questions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am aware about the official reference, but does anyone/official Spring example SVN have Spring 3 IoC tutorial with working source code in IDE project, that I can compile and run immediately. There are number for old Spring 2 tutorials about IoC with examples in the web, but not Spring 3 as I can find. Thanks.